# What is the mess with ruby encoding?

Tags: ruby

I'm currently having troubles with Ruby string encoding. It's supposed to be UTF-8 by default but when I'm using IRB I get:

```
irb(main):001:0> s="Oï"
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        2: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        1: from /usr/share/gems/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
SyntaxError ((irb):1: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII))
(irb):1: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
irb(main):002:0> s="Oï"
=> "O\u00EF"
irb(main):003:0> s="Oï"
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        2: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        1: from /usr/share/gems/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
SyntaxError ((irb):3: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII))
(irb):3: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
irb(main):004:0> s="Oï"
=> "O\u00EF"
```

Typing exactly the same assignment leads to different results.
What's happening? What did I miss?

```
$ irb -v      
irb 1.0.0 (2018-12-18)
$ gem -v   
3.0.3
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
$ uname -a
Linux P9X79 5.3.6-200.fc30.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 14 13:11:01 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You might try updating IRB (`gem update irb`) as the current version is 1.1.0. Running the assignment on my Mac OS works without errors. What does your `locale` command show? Copy and paste the information from the command-line into your question and format it appropriately. Don't use "edited" or "updated" tags as we can see what changed, just insert it as if it'd always been there.

Comment: Works fine under WSL with `LANG=C.UTF-8`.

Comment: What's your terminal set to? If it's not UTF-8 that would explain. The terminal and the terminal's environment (`LANG`) should match.

Comment: Got it! Made it work by changing LANG=C to LANG=C.UTF-8.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have no idea why the results differ between attempts. But my guess for the error is `LANG` environmental variable is not set to accept UTF-8, as pointed out, given the output in the successful attempts shows `"O\u00EF"` as opposed to `"Oï"`. Have you tried `s="O\u00EF"` ? If this works, it means irb handles the String correctly internally.